# Best programming based games

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Back when I was at school, I remember tinkering with a Mac game where you programmed little robots in a sort of pseudo-assembler language which could then battle each other. They could move themselves around the arena, look for opponents in different directions, and fire some sort of weapon. Pretty basic stuff, but I remember it quite fondly, even if I can't remember the name.

Are there any good modern day equivalents?

Comment: no one mentioned mindrover

Comment: something pretty new: http://www.nessbots.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game in question was definitely Robowar for the Mac. My son had a lot of fun with it and went on to program real robots.

As mentioned earlier by Proud, there is a wiki page for it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboWar

Although there has not been a lot of activity surrounding the game over the last few years, there was a tournament held recently, and there is a yahoo email group.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Battle Seems to be a modern version :)

Answer (score 34):

I used to have a lot of fun coding my own robot with [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) in college.

It is Java based, the API is detailled and it's pretty easy to get a challenging robot up and running.

Here is an example :

```
 public class MyFirstRobot extends Robot {
     public void run() {
         while (true) {
             ahead(100);
             turnGunRight(360);
             back(100);
             turnGunRight(360);
         }
     }

     public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
         fire(1);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 32):

Just found [Light Bot](http://armorgames.com/play/2205/light-bot).  Program your robot to move around and perform tasks to complete a puzzle.  Even includes subroutines. Program the bot by dragging tiles into slots. The game is very polished.

**Update** [Lightbot](http://light-bot.com) is now the most recent version of the game, and has versions specifically designed for kids ages 4-8 or ages 9+ (with no upper limit) and also features kind of an *if*

[screen of lightbot 1 http://www.lostateminor.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/light-bot.jpg](http://www.lostateminor.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/light-bot.jpg)

Comment: I played the first one, and it was very nicely done, but not played the second yet. I hack, my wife doesn't, and we both enjoyed playing it.

Answer (score 24):

I think the original game was called [Core Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) (this Wikipedia article contains a lot of interesting links); there still seem to be programs and competitions around, for example at [corewars.org](http://www.corewars.org/). I never had the time to look into these games, but they seem like great fun.

Comment: just a side note: corewars stuff is written in their own version of assembly.

Comment: Actually reading the question makes it clear it's definitely not Core War!  Instead it's likely to be either RoboWar, RobotWar or C-Robots.

Comment: The RedCode is annoying - I'd much prefer to write in a less dense language.

Answer (score 19):

In the flash game [Manufactoria](http://www.kongregate.com/games/PleasingFungus/manufactoria) you "program" a factory by laying out the conveyor belts and switches in a way that's very similar to a FSM, but more powerful. **This game is really great.** Give it a try, especially if you're into formal languages and automata!

[Manufactoria screen shot http://www.tomdalling.com/wp-content/uploads/manufactoria-bubble-sort.png](http://www.tomdalling.com/wp-content/uploads/manufactoria-bubble-sort.png)

Comment: It would have been nice if you quoted your probable [source](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/what-are-some-programming-games-that-are-out-there-closed) and split this up into separate answers :-<

Comment: Actually, those are all games I've played and liked. I didn't know the link you gave.

Comment: in that case I apologize. It just seemed such little chance that this was coincidence. But +1 for using wine and a crowded desktop just like mine :) Anyway, you should split this up into one answer per game for better voting, or rather edit the screenshot of Lightbot into the already exsiting answer (that's what CW is for, after all)

Comment: @Tobias Actually I didn't do the screen capture myself, I've stolen it using Google search. But I've run Bug Brain using Wine, too.

Answer (score 17):

A game in which you have to graphically construct and train artificial neural networks in order to control a bug is [Bug Brain](http://www.biologic.com.au/bugbrain/).

[Bug Brain screen shot http://www.infionline.net/~wtnewton/oldcomp/bugbrain.jpg](http://www.infionline.net/~wtnewton/oldcomp/bugbrain.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 7 64 bit. :c

Answer (score 12):

If you want to step away from your keyboard, Wizards of the Coast relased a game called RoboRally that is a combative programming board game.

http://www.wizards.com/roborally/

Comment: This is an excellent party game, if you can hold the attention of all your fellow rally-mates.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.pythonchallenge.com/

highly addictive, and a great way to learn python

Comment: I think this stretches the definition of "game", but in a good way.  Lots of fun.

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised that Space Chem isn't mentioned yet. Programming with symbols, but programming nevertheless.

http://spacechemthegame.com/

Comment: Actually, as far as Zachtronics goes The Codex is far more streamlined programming-wise: http://www.zachtronics.com/games/

Answer (score 6):

Another good one is [CEEBot](http://www.ceebot.com/ceebot/index-e.php).  It teaches C / Java style programming in a fun, robot-programming kind of game.  It is aimed at 10-15 year olds, but it is a good one.

Comment: There is CeeBot-Teen for 10-15 year olds and also CeeBot-A for adults. Their site says (15-99).

Answer (score 6):

[Colobot](http://www.ceebot.com/colobot/index-e.php)

It's usually easy for new programmers to pick up on languages like C++ when you have a strong understanding of Java basics. Colobot allows you to program automated craft using a language almost identical to Java and to move, sense, and manipulate their environment in order to accomplish missions on a dangerous planet.

Answer (score 5):

I was also keen on these kind of games. One modern example which I have used is http://www.robotbattle.com/. There are various others - for example the ones listed at http://www.google.com/Top/Games/Video_Games/Simulation/Programming_Games/Robotics/

Answer (score 5):

Core Wars is the classic, of course. But [Rocky's Boots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky's_Boots) is another one. Imagine! There was a time (1982) when you could sell a commercial game based on logic gates!

Comment: I loved Rocky's Boots -- I played it on Apple II.

Comment: Another vote for Rocky's Boots (Apple ][e)...playing it when I was 8 ended up helping me pass EE 316 in college!

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to look at single player games like Light Bot and  Manufactoria then I highly recommend **[RoboZZle](http://www.robozzle.com)**. It has conditional commands which include function calls. This allows for complex stack manipulation. There are thousands of user created puzzles from pathetically obvious to mind blowing enigmas. They have recently added support for smartphones.

I also think **[The Codex of Alchemical Engineering](http://www.kongregate.com/games/krispykrem/the-codex-of-alchemical-engineering)** is worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

I think [.NET Terrarium](http://www.codeplex.com/terrarium2) is one of the best 'learn-to-program' games for the .NET platform.

Answer (score 4):

I like [Ruby Warrior](http://github.com/ryanb/ruby-warrior/tree/master). It is still somewhat under development, but it is a great game with a clever interface.

Answer (score 3):

[Core Wars](http://www.corewars.org/)

Answer (score 3):

There's also [mySQLgame](http://mysqlgame.appspot.com/), I found it pretty amusing (shortly after finding out I suck).

[Here's what Casual Gameplay has to say about it.](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2008/08/mysqlgame.php)

Answer (score 3):

[Kara](http://www.swisseduc.ch/compscience/karatojava/index.html) is about programming a bug(!) coming up in various versions, e.g. Finite State Machine, Java, Turing Machine, Multithreading

[Kara http://www.swisseduc.ch/compscience/karatojava/kara/icons/kara-worldeditor.gif](http://www.swisseduc.ch/compscience/karatojava/kara/icons/kara-worldeditor.gif)

Answer (score 3):

[Planetwars](http://ai-contest.com/) is a game specifically written for Google Ai Contest, bots are controlling fleets for conquering planets, they support many languages

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the most famous programming game there has been is the [core wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War). I don't know if you can still find active "rings" although there was a lot when I tried it some time ago (4 or 5 years).

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard or Core Wars before, but it looks interesting. I do have to vouch for RoboCode, though. That's fun and challenging, especially if you have a group of people competing against either other.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(computer_game)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_2

There is also a great hacking game the name of which I simply cannot remember. Hrm.

Answer (score 2):

Matt, I think the game you're referring to is [CRobots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crobots) (or one of its clones, perhaps -- my first contact was with PRobots, in Pascal, if I remember correctly). It was a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

While it was more logic than programming per se, one I really enjoyed back in elementary school was [Rocky's Boots](http://www.warrenrobinett.com/rockysboots/).  It had sensors, AND gates, OR gates, NOT gates, wires, timers, and all sorts of other stuff.  Fantastic program for teaching a kid logic.

Go to the link and you can still play it!

Answer (score 2):

[Carnage Heart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnage_Heart) for PlayStation was fun. It would let you program little mechs to do battle using a flow diagram.

[image: The Brain]

Answer (score 1):

I have to give a shout out to [RobotWar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RobotWar) which was the first programming "game" that I played way back in the Apple II days. It was written by Silas Warner of Castle Wolfenstein fame.

Answer (score 1):

I got myself addicted to [uplink](http://www.introversion.co.uk/uplink/) a few months ago. It's not really coding based, more hacking. It's still fun and super geeky.

Answer (score 1):

Although not strictly programming-based, I enjoyed a lot [Robot Odyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Odyssey), a game where you wired logic gates to sensors and motors in a robot, to make it move and react to environment, to get out of a city, escaping obstacles. I played in on Apple //e, it was one of the best games on this computer (with Lode Runner! :-)).

Answer (score 1):

You must be thinking of [RoboWar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboWar). Oh how lovely it is.

Still exists, though the community is slowly dying.

http://robowar.sourceforge.net/RoboWar5/index.html
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/robowar/

Answer (score 1):

There's racing car simulator game [TORCS](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/) also where on top of the typical end user playing it (you actually "driving" the cars), you can program robots which control the cars. Regular races are held between robots created by different people.

Answer (score 1):

Another game in this vein is [Origin's Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_(1989_computer_game)). Tanks are constructed on a budget, and then the user programs them in a BASIC-like language with a structured editor. The tanks battle on fields with varying terrain.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite was [PCRobots](http://www.pscs.co.uk/pcrobots/) back in the 90's - you could write your bot in pretty much any language that could compile a DOS executable. Still runs quite nicely in [DOSBox](http://dosbox.com/) :)

Comment: Finally I found the one I played around when I was a student!! Thanks for the answer mate!!

Answer (score 1):

[Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_%28computer_game%29) is one of them, I played it on C64 :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Spanish Java Page who organice a football leage in wich the users program the skills of their team and the strategy. You only need to download the framework and implement a little interface, then you can simulate matchs which are seen in the screen. When you are happy with your team and strategy you submit the code to the page and enters in the tournament.

Tutorials, videos and downloads:

[Java Cup](http://javacup.javahispano.org)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find the original game I was thinking of - I think it was called 'bots or something like that, and ran on my Mac back in around system 6 days. I'll have to do some digging next time I'm back at my parents place.

Thinking more about it over the last day or so, I suppose it's really not all that different to writing brains for bolo (http://www.lgm.com/bolo/) or bots for Quake and those sort of games.

Comment: Maxis RoboSport perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The game was Robowar--I used to play a bit back in college. [Here's the wiki for it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboWar) I guess it's now open source and available on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I played RoboWar, but the programming game I remember on the Mac was [Chipwits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipwits). It came out in 1984. Completely graphical, but entertaining. From what I've seen of Lego Mindstorms, the programming style is similar.

Answer (score 0):

For a modern equivalent, check out [CodeRally](http://www-304.ibm.com/jct01005c/university/students/highschool/coderally.html), it's a Java programming challenge where you write a class to control a race car. The car drives around a track trying to hit check points, refilling when the gas tank runs low, and avoiding obstacles. I think you can throw tires at your opponents. You can run a tournament with several players submitting code to a central server.

There are several other programming games listed on [IBM's high school outreach page](https://www-927.ibm.com/ibm/cas/hspc/games.html#ProgrammingGames), including [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) that others already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting historical game is the old [Robot Odyssey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Odyssey), which was essentially a game where you programmed robots by building logic circuits out of gates and flip flops. I remembered it clearly when I took real EE classes over a decade later.

Answer (score 0):

[AI Bots II](http://aibots.sourceforge.net/) is a programmer's game. Instead of playing the game directly, players are required to write a program to do it.

There is an arena where two teams of players (called bots) are loaded. Each team needs one program, multiple instances of which will control each player of that team.
[...]
You write your program in C/C++.
Your program runs parallely with the game.

*(copied this description directly from the game homepage)*

Answer (score 0):

I have so far found the game [Cells](https://github.com/phreeza/cells) to be quite satisfying.

The whole object of the game is to program a "hive mind", which is capable of surviving, breeding, and destroying its enemies.

Lots are good "minds" are provided by the author and various contributors, and it's easy to write others by looking at them.

However, the author seems to be progressing on it very slowly - the last commit was about a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

In [Grobots](http://grobots.sourceforge.net/) you give a program for various types of robots in your army (think gatherers, fighters, builders). And the best: they can replicate. Comes with its own programming language.

[image]