# Which games include coding in gameplay?

Tags: language-agnostic, list

One title per answer.

Comment: Similar question: [Best programming based games](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952/best-programming-based-games)

Answer (score 15):

Core War (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_war) is the classic, where two programs run in a simulated machine, each trying to halt the other one.

Answer (score 12):

[Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) is a great way to learn Java and have fun doing it. You write Java code to program a robot, which then battles it out against one or more other robots. It's years ago I tried it, but I remember having great fun doing it. We even programmed robots at work (in between the *real* work ;) ) and had a small competition going to see who could come up with the best algorithms. Recommended!

Answer (score 8):

http://gr1d.org is a persistent online programming rpg, where you write your own agents, advance in levels and attack or defend other players

Answer (score 7):

[RoboRally!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboRally)

Comment: Yeah, you gotta love that one!

Answer (score 7):

A little Flash game I found the other day: http://www.gameroo.nl/games/light-bot

Be careful, you will likely lose about an hour of your life ;)

Comment: Stupid 3rd last level, reminds me of doing card house programming on micro controllers :P

Answer (score 3):

[Lists and Lists: An interactive tutorial](http://www.wurb.com/if/game/128) by Andrew Plotkin.

> "An introductory course in the Scheme programming language (a dialect of Lisp) presented as a text adventure - or, to put it another way, a Scheme interpreter with a wee scrap of text adventure wrapped around it. Since it's Z-code, and the first Z-code games were written in another Lisp variant, there's an odd circularity to it all."

- Carl Muckenhoupt

Answer (score 3):

Years ago, I wasted way too much time on [Omega](http://www.the-underdogs.info/game.php?id=783)

Answer (score 2):

Second Life

Answer (score 1):

Life?

Answer (score 1):

[Crobots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crobots)

Answer (score 1):

Discover fundamentals of computer programming by playing a board game; c-jump helps children to learn basics of programming languages, such as C, C++ and Java.

http://www.c-jump.com/

Answer (score 1):

GNU Robots (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Robots) is a great way to get stuck into Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

Starship Soccer (http://www.geocities.com/siliconvalley/horizon/8596/StarshipSoccer.html) pits C++ controlled teams against each other, playing a mix of Space War and football.

Answer (score 1):

Good list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_game)!

> Programming games of note include Core
>   War, Robocode, RoboWar, Robot Battle,
>   Crobots and AI Wars. Final Fantasy XII
>   also includes some elements of a
>   programming game, as the player
>   creates the AI of his characters,
>   although the player can also choose to
>   directly control the action.

Answer (score 1):

EpsiTec [CeeBot](http://www.ceebot.com/ceebot/family-e.php)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Terrarium](http://www.codeplex.com/terrarium2), which involved programming the intelligence of a creature using any .Net language, has now been open sourced to [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/terrarium2)